# Requisição com FETCH API fica repetindo

Tags: fetch

Quando envio o formulário para o servidor, os dados são cadastrados, normalmente, no banco de dados. Entretanto, ao observar no *network* do meu *browser*, sempre há duas requisições enviadas, como abaixo:

> ```
> 1 - sendAjax @   category.js:47
> formCategory.addEventListener    @   VM968 category.js:13
> ```

> ```
> 2 - sendAjax @   category.js:47
> formCategory.addEventListener    @   category.js:13
> ```

Percebam que as requisições são diferenciadas por: `VM968`, descrito no item 1

Tenho feito a requisição para o *laravel*, porém, quando faço a requisição sem o *laravel*, isto não acontece!

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: O método HTTP não é diferente? As requisições são feitas para um domínio diferente? Pois se esse for o caso, pode ser uma verificação de cross-domain.

Comment: Isso acontece com qualquer método. Acredito que deva ser uma verificação interna do laravel, cross-domain...Mas preciso ter a certeza que não é um bug! Já desenvolvi em laravel e, isso jamais acontecia!

Comment: Pessoal, resolvi o problema. O problema era nas rotas. Havia uma rota duplicada, para a mesma requisição!